# Why do I get error, KeyError: 'wsgi.input'?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I'm using WSGI and trying to access the get/post data, using this code:

```
import os
import cgi
from traceback import format_exception
from sys import exc_info

def application(environ, start_response):

    try:
        f = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=os.environ['wsgi.input'], environ=os.environ)
        output = 'Test: %s' % f['test'].value
    except:
        output = ''.join(format_exception(*exc_info()))

    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

However I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/www/vm/custom/gettest.wsgi", line 9, in application
    f = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=os.environ['wsgi.input'], environ=os.environ)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/UserDict.py", line 17, in __getitem__
    def __getitem__(self, key): return self.data[key]
KeyError: 'wsgi.input'
```

Is it because wsgi.input does not exist in my version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misusing the [WSGI API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#specification-details).

Please create a minimal ("hello world") function that shows this error so we can comment on your code.  [Don't post your entire application, it may be too big and unwieldy for us to comment on.]

The `os.environ` is not what you should be using.  WSGI replaces this with an enriched environment.  A WSGI application gets two arguments: one is a dictionary that includes `'wsgi.input'`.

---

In your code...

```
def application(environ, start_response):

    try:
        f = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=os.environ['wsgi.input'], environ=os.environ)
```

Per the WSGI API specification (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#specification-details), don't use `os.environ`.  Use `environ`, the first positional parameter to your application.

> The environ parameter is a dictionary
>   object, containing CGI-style
>   environment variables. This object
>   must be a builtin Python dictionary
>   (not a subclass, UserDict or other
>   dictionary emulation), and the
>   application is allowed to modify the
>   dictionary in any way it desires. The
>   dictionary must also include certain
>   WSGI-required variables (described in
>   a later section), and may also include
>   server-specific extension variables,
>   named according to a convention that
>   will be described below.

Comment: Pasted some more elaborate sample code. Please let me know I should change it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that environ was an argument of my method. Silly mistake I think.